# Error 1061, can't fix

Tags: actionscript-3, constructor, static

Pretty new to AS3, still trying to get this to work. Getting a 1061 error when doing this.

Here's the code I have on the .fla file:

```
import ResizableBox;

var resizeBox:ResizableBox = new ResizableBox();

ResizableBox.startResize();
```

And then in the file named ResizableBox.as, here's the code for that:

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

    public class ResizableBox extends MovieClip{
        public function ResizableBox(){
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startResize);
        }

        private function startResize(e:MouseEvent):void{
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleResize);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopResize);
        }

        private function stopResize(e:MouseEvent):void{
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleResize);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopResize);
        }

        private function handleResize(e:MouseEvent):void{
            this.scaleY = 1
            this.height = this.mouseY
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why I'm getting the error. I've also tried adding a static component to the public function, but then I get a 1026 error (Constructor functions must be instance methods). I've looked for what I've been doing wrong, but I can't figure it out.

I also have the source path set properly to the folder containing the .as file.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Changed ResizableBox.startResize(); to resizeBox.startResize(null);

Changed startResize function from private for public.

Now when I run the thing, I get no errors, until I move to the frame with this code.

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@1ddcc6a1 to ResizableBox.

    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at CubeTotem_Test_fla::MainTimeline/goSettings()[CubeTotem_Test_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:27]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at ResizableBox/startResize()[C:\Users\Ecco T1\Documents\ResizableBox.as:12]
    at CubeTotem_Test_fla::MainTimeline/frame6()[CubeTotem_Test_fla.MainTimeline::frame6:20]
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at CubeTotem_Test_fla::MainTimeline/goSettings()[CubeTotem_Test_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:27]
```

I'm trying to get a simple square to be scaled win the Y direction when clicked and dragged.

FINAL EDIT: Got it to work! I had to convert the box to a symbol and tick "Export to Actionscript" and give it the proper class label. Now I just need to move it from the top-left corner because it doesn't show up on the stage unless I play the animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .fla, replace:

```
ResizableBox.startResize();
```

with

```
resizeBox.startResize(null);
```

Explanation:

1. startResize() is coded to take one parameter (a MouseEvent object). Your are calling it without giving it a parameter. Calling it with a null reference might not be best practice, but you can do that.
2. You are trying to call that method on your ResizableBox **class** (it is not a static method, so it doesn't find it). You need to call the method on the **object** you created (i.e. resizeBox).

Hope this solves your problem.

*EDIT1: You said it works fine until you "move to the frame with this code". Is "this code" the code you wrote in the question? Or is it another piece of code?

*EDIT2: Oh, how I hate remote debugging... Try adding `this.addChild(resizeBox);` and delete the `resizeBox.startResize(null);` line (or just comment it)

*EDIT3: I think you might be doing something wrong there. Could you post the code from the `goSettings` method?

*EDIT4: So the initial code you posted is from frame 6. Can you post the whole code from that frame?

Comment: Sorry bout that, the original error text is "1061: Call to a possibly undefined method startResize through a reference with static type Class."

I tried your suggestion and got: "1195: Attempted access of inaccessible method startResize through a reference with static type ResizableBox."

Comment: So how would I go about calling it on an object? I can't put code onto a movieclip

Comment: Ok, I figured that it was a call to a possibly undefined method, but I wasn't sure. I edited my answer, adding an explanation. Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Just replace that third line you posted from the fla with the one I suggested.

Comment: Oh, yes, didn't see it was a private method. GoldRoger solved it.

Comment: I get two errors when I try his method. A 1034 and 1009.

Comment: In that case, I think you need to give more details. And I have a hunch it will be a long conversation. Unfortunately, I can't start a chat, because I'm new on SO. This being said, try to post the whole error text and say what you are trying to achieve and what you have done so far. I suggest you edit your question, adding said details.

Comment: Updated and gave the errors and what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: "This code" is the code in the question, I just don't have it on frame one. I use a button to navigate to this frame with "this code"

Comment: I hate remote debugging as well, but thanks for your effort!

So that got rid of the 1009 error, but I still have the type coercion error.

Comment: a function that takes you to this frame from frame 1

Comment: settings_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goSettings);

function goSettings(e:MouseEvent):void{
 gotoAndStop(6);
}

Answer (score 0):

Make your `startResize` method of `ResizableBox` public..

```
public function startResize(e:MouseEvent):void{
```

Then in fla file, call the method from object..

```
var resizeBox:ResizableBox = new ResizableBox();

resizeBox.startResize(null);
```

Comment: No compiler errors, but when I go to the frame that holds the code I get 2 TypeErrors, 1034 and 1009.

Comment: Also, let me say that this function is trying to make a square scale in the Y direction when clicked on and dragged (like a slider).